GD extension for PHP loaded in CLI but not in Apache 2
I am trying to setup a local Apache + PHP webserver on an Android device (using Termux), and I am a complete beginner in both Apache and PHP.
(I know setting up a server on an Android device does not feel right, but it is for a VR headset - I want the VR experiences, which are in php - not my choice - to be loaded from the VR headset itself without relying on an Internet connection).
My issue is that I can't get the gd module to load in Apache.
The GD module is correctly loaded in the CLI, but not on my Apache server.
When I run php -i, I get the following key info (redacted for clarity):
Configure Command => [...] 'enable-gd=shared,/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/' '--with-external-gd' [...]
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/php/
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/php/conf.d/gd.ini

And the content of gd.ini is:
extension=gd

It seems to me it is working correctly because:

there is a module section named gd in the output of php -i;
when I run var_dump(gd_info()); in a php console (php -a), it works (I have a list of variables).

Now when I show php_info() from a .php file with Apache, I have all the exact same information as the output of php -i listed above. There is still no php.ini configuration file loaded, and the gd.ini file is the same. However there is no GD module section, and if I load a page trying to show gd_info(), I get an error: 'Call to undefined function gd_info()'.
I have tried loading a php.ini by uncommenting extension=gd, setting extension_dir and specifying the correct PHPIniDir in httpd.conf, but it (unsurprisingly) didn't help., even though I could see that the php.ini was successfully loaded.
I am probably missing something obvious but I feel I'm out of ideas.
Thanks!

Did you restart the php-fpm after those changes?

No, but I just checked and apparently it is not installed
